# MFI for iBeacon/ Estimotes?

Tags: core-location, core-bluetooth, ibeacon, mfi, estimote

Does a hardware that needs to advertise BLE signals as an iBeacon need to be MFI certified? I have noticed that is easy to turn a Raspberry Pi into a device that can send out iBeacons.

I looked at Estimotes, and nowhere does it say that it MFI certified.

Will the CoreLocation API specific to iBeacons work with a non-MFI certified beaconing hardware?

Comment: iBeacons work with Bluetooth Low-Energy which are not constraints to MFi.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be part of the MFi Developer program, but if you want to use the iBeacon logo or market your product as being iBeacon compatible, you will need to be part of the [iBeacon Program](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/)

As for Estimotes, I am assuming that they are in the program because they have the iBeacon logo under their 'certificates' section.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's iBeacon certification program is the specific MFi-variant that applies to beacons.  **My company makes [Raspberry Pi-based beacons](http://store.radiusnetworks.com/collections/all) that are iBeacon Certified** as well as battery-powered and USB-powered units.

The certification program is a way of making sure that beacons meet Apple's requirements for proper operation.   Vendors who make beacons that aren't certified may work just fine for development purposes.  Often times, however, the broadcast frequency of these beacons is pretty slow (1 Hz or less to save battery power), which can make for less accurate distance estimates when using ranging APIs.  Just make sure you test with these beacons before counting on them!

Comment: Thanks davidgyoung. So are you saying that I can build my own Raspberry Pi based beacons, but not go through iBeacon certification (I'm not interested in using the iBeacon logo or market my product as being iBeacon compatible) - then my beacons can be detected easily by the CoreLocation APIs ? i.e - locationManager:didEnterRegion: and locationManager:didExitRegion: will still be called when my iPhone enters the region broadcasted by my Raspberry Pi?

Comment: From an engineering perspective, yes, it is absolutely possible to do what you describe.

Comment: Ok, so even from a business perspective, can I be able to sell a beaconing hardware without going through MFi certification, as long as my app can region monitor itself with reference to my hardware (since I don't truly intend to make the hardware work with other third party apps, and hence don't need an iBeacon logo) ?  If this is possible, based on your first post, were you saying there could be performance concerns?

Comment: I have to stick to the engineering side as that is my expertise.  (Although I will note that plenty of folks do sell uncertified beacons.)  The performance concerns I mention have nothing to do with certification -- they have to do with the way that some manufacturers make beacons such that they advertise infrequently and therefore get very poor distance estimates.  Certification can help combat problems like these by specifying minimum acceptable performance criteria.  But you don't have to be certified to design a good product that works well.